# Is there any alternatives of glClearTexImage() in OpenGL 4.1?

Tags: macos, opengl

I am wirting code in MacOS which only support OpenGL 4.1 now.
and I create an framebuffer color attachment for mouse picking which return an int value.

```c
// glsl code here
layout(location = 1) out int color2;
...

void main(){
   ...
   color2 = 50;
}
```

```cpp
// create RED_INTEGER color attachment
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
```

And now I need to clear this buffer by value=-1.

I know there are glClearTexImage()in OpenGL 4.4  like:

```cpp
int value = -1;
glClearTexImage(colorAttachmentID, 0, RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, &value);
```

Is there any way to clear such buffer below OpenGL 4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glClearBuffer*` family of functions can be used to [clear specific framebuffer attached images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Buffer_clearing). There are integer forms of these functions.

Your code would look like:

```
GLint values[4] = {-1};
glClearBuffer(GL_COLOR, X, &value);
```

Where `X` is the color attachment index, the number you added to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` when you attached it to the framebuffer.

Be aware that buffer clearing always respects the scissor test if it is enabled. So it will only clear within that region.

Also, don't treat this function as an alternative to `glClearTexImage`. It is the *correct* function to use if the image you're clearing is being used as a framebuffer image.